# ASP.NET ReportViewer body borders/lines

Tags: asp.net, layout, reportviewer

How can I add borders to the body section of a report?  I have lines on the left and right side of the body section (top to bottom), as well as "middle of the page" markers that intersect these lines.  I want these lines to repeat on each page of the report, which contains numerous subreports.

I tried creating a hidden table in the body, and then told the lines to repeat with the table.  However, the top to bottom lines on the left and right show up only on the first page, while the small middle markers show up after all subreport content.

Any advice on how to add repeating, free form lines to a report body is appreciated.

I am using Visual Studio 2008 Professional on .NET 3.5 using ASP.NET WebForms.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your body must have a List Item. You can add on the properties box the BorderColor, BorderStyle and BorderWidht